# RMySQL, dbWriteTable, and text fields containing newlines

Tags: mysql, r, text, rmysql

I have an R routine which needs to write text from third parties to a MySQL database.  That text often contains newlines.

Unfortunately,

```
foobar <- as.data.frame(a=1, b='\n')
dbWriteTable(MySQL(), foobar, 'test')
```

creates a table with *two* records; the '\n' generates a record break and an empty record.

IS there something special about RMySQL?  Is this a well known issue?  I've looked around a lot, and I haven't seen anyone discuss it.  Is there a workaround short of using a different connector?

Comment: I found a hack which serves my purposes, although it's not going to always work: if you URL escape the text, then it contains no invalid characters and can be recovered verbatim.

I'm going to try to reach the package maintainer and see if he or she has a better solution, or if this is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

```
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user='user', password='password')

foobar <- as.data.frame(a=1, b='\n')
foobar$b <- dbEscapeStrings(con, foobar$b)
dbWriteTable(con, foobar, 'test')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty easy to solve, it turns out.

There's a function called dbEscapeStrings in the DBI interface.  It transforms strings into a form in which they'll be stored correctly in a database- and locale-sensitive fashion.  If you transform the strings this way before you pass them across the gap, then they get stored correctly in the table.